# Menu items to be included in Hamburger

Tags: website-design, hamburger

I have a doubt about the menu items that should go in the hamburger menu. Following are the pics of a sample website I am working on.

The first image is without user login and has menus that are not relevant to the user or his profile.

[image]

The second image is after the user logs in to the website. Here you can see his avatar and link to the dashboard.

[image]

I want to know whether this is right according to the UX to put the menu items like Blog/Contact/About/Careers in the hamburger menu of the website? I think that the hamburger must contain only Dashboard and Logout menu where as the other menu should go to the footer or somewhere else on the page. Also, whether the hamburger should be used for the desktop website or not, as hamburger is related to mobile and mobile apps.

Note: The hamburger icon and the avatar icon are different and clicking on both shows the menu.

Comment: [To hamburger or not to hamburger, that is the question.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles if to be, than the content too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing first:** If this is for desktop, then you should NOT use a hamburger menu. However, if you're decided to do it, just test it and see how it goes.

If this is for mobile, then proceed to the second part :)

And **what you think is correct**. There should be 2 different menus. To avoid confusions, it's common to name one of the menus **NAVIGATION**, while any other menu will be called a menu. This is important, because here's what you're correctly perceiving: there's one menu (the navigation one) which acts as a way to access the different parts of the site.

On the other hand, you have a member's area with its own set of actions and behaviours, so it needs to go in a different menu.

Let's take [**Material Design**](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-usage) as an example

> A menu is a temporary piece of material that appears upon interaction
>   with a button, action, pointer, or other control. It contains at least
>   two menu items.
>
> Each menu item consists of a discrete option or action that can affect
>   the app, the view, or selected elements within a view.
>
> **Menus should not be used as a primary method for navigation within an
>   app.**

And see the *hamburger* menu (left) used for navigation and the *kebab* menu (right) used for settings and app related behaviours, such as yours

[image]
[image]

**BONUS:** Just for reference, the funny names after the menus *(hamburger, kebab and such)*:

[image]

Comment: +1 I never heard of the Bento, Kebab, Doner, or Meatballs. The Double Hamburger Menu is kind of weird, what is the actual difference between the two?

Comment: @Alvaro, I have no idea, would never use that! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mixing two things, a menu and a sidebar navigation drawer.

- Menus. In [Material design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#), a menu:

> Each menu item consists of a discrete option or action that can affect the app, the view, or selected elements within a view.
>
> **Menus should not be used as a primary method for navigation within an app**.

- Navigation drawer. In [Material design](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns), a navigation drawer:

> - Apps with many top-level views
> - Enabling quick navigation between unrelated views
> - Deep navigation structures
> - Reducing visibility of infrequent destinations